# Texture Causing Everything Else to Dim

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm working on a program that maps out the stars in the sky relative to your location and time of day. After the stars are mapped out, the constellation lines are drawn and then pictures of the constellations as well.

The way that I was using to put the pictures in is creating a rectangle and then applying a texture of the constellation to it. The problem I'm having is that when I apply the texture, everything else in the program gets really dark, dark enough to where i can almost not see it.

I narrowed it down to glTexParameteri somehow but I still don't know what to do to fix it.

My goal is to have the texture shown on screen without dimming everything else around it.

Comment: Can you show what you've done (code)? Before and after images would be helpful as well (you can post links to them)

Answer (score 1):

Use glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_…); to disable textureing. Without doing so the very last texture coordinate and texture used is applied to the following primitives.